# Foreach multi dimensional array

Tags: php, laravel-8

I have this array

```
$zone = [{"Bertoua Zone 3":[{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"4","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"10","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"7","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"4","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"3","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"3","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"2","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"}],"Bertoua Zone 1":[{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"5","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"3","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"7","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"15","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"5","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"4","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"}]}]
```

i want to get this result

```
$recapByZone = [{"Bertoua Zone 3":[{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"7","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"14","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"12","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},],"Bertoua Zone 1":[{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"20","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"8","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"11","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"}]}]
```

Comment: where is your code!? and what is difference between those to array?

Comment: I want to sum quantity of item with same code in specific zone

Answer (score 1):

I've done my best and it differs slightly from your sample code.

See https://onecompiler.com/php/3ybbmywrp

```
 $zone = '[{"Bertoua Zone 3":[{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"4","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"10","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"7","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"4","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"3","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"3","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"2","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"}],"Bertoua Zone 1":[{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"5","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"3","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"7","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"15","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"5","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"4","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"}]}]';
        $zone = json_decode($zone, true);

        $zone2 = '[{"Bertoua Zone 3":[{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"7","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"14","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"12","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 3"}],"Bertoua Zone 1":[{"code":"MNY65C","product_quantity":"20","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"JAP65C","product_quantity":"8","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"},{"code":"BFT50C","product_quantity":"11","zone_name":"Bertoua Zone 1"}]}]';
        $zone2 = json_decode($zone2, true);

        $result = [];
        foreach ($zone[0] as $key => $element) {
            foreach ($element as $value) {
                if (isset($result[$key][$value['code']])) {
                    $result[0][$key][$value['code']]['product_quantity'] += $value['product_quantity'];
                } else {
                    $result[0][$key][$value['code']] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        echo print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<hr>';
        echo '<pre>';
        echo print_r($zone2);
        echo '</pre>';
```